# "Where not exists" vs "left outer join" in oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a simple SQL query:

```
SELECT  
       columnA, columnB, columnC...  
 FROM  
       (SELECT    
             columnA, columnB, columnC...  
        FROM   
              SomeTable) Table1  
  WHERE NOT EXISTS  
        (SELECT   
               columnA  
          FROM  
               SomeOtherTable st  
          WHERE  
               st.columnB = Table1.columnB)
```

Can anyone give me a suggestion how to rewrite this query for better performance? I mean to include the `WHERE NOT EXISTS` clause in Table1.

Comment: Is the subquery `SELECT FROM (SELECT ...)` necessary in your query? Without seeing exactly what the optimizer is doing it's hard to say, but this is probably where the hangup is.

Comment: "Better performance" is completely dependent on your own personal circumstances. You need to provide the real query (as small a version as possible to demonstrate what you'd like to improve) the structure of the tables including indexes, the explain plan you're currently getting and some example data. Only then will people be able to set up the same circumstances and provide an objective measure. As it stands I'm sorry but your question is unanswerable (or at least any answers you get will mean very little to nothing).

Comment: @lc., it doesn't appear to be necessary but Oracle will normally act as if it's not there anyway so it makes little difference.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use this:

```
select Table1.*
from (select * from SomeTable) Table1
left outer join SomeOtherTable sot
    on Table1.columnB = sot.columnB
where sot.columnB is null;
```

For the performance it is important to have indexes on `columnB` on both tables.

Comment: I can't use this form because at the end of "where not exists" condition there is a synonym for Table1

Comment: @slyder07: I don't understand your comment. Please rephrase it. There is nothing preventing you from using the solution I provided.

Comment: I can't use this form because at the end of "where not exists" condition there is a synonym for Table1 (... where st.columnB = **Table1**.columnB). The "where" condition from second table points to Table1

Comment: @slyder07: So what? Your comment still doesn't make sense. `Table1` is the synonym for a sub query. This sub query doesn't do anything that's why I left it out in my answer. I added it back in now... Have a look

Comment: Thx Daniel, i finally undertood you solution, it really worked. Unfortunately execution was  not increased in my case.... columnB does not have indexes...

Comment: @slyder07: You need to add those indexes :)

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
SELECT columnA, columnB, columnC... 
FROM SomeTable
WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM  SomeOtherTable st  WHERE  st.columnB = SomeTable.columnB)=0;
```

Comment: I really want to remove the "where not exists" at all, for better performance, my real querry run for an half hour

Comment: How about checking the second table's row count?